# how can I read in octet-stream file and convert to utf-8?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have got an Application/octet-stream file and want to read into memory encoded as utf-8. How can I do that with Python ?
what is actually Application/octet-stream?

I have tried

```
import codecs
codecs.open('file/name','rb',encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')
```

But it does not work:

```
the result is 

u'\xOOA\x00r\x00'
```

what I want is in alphabet

thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

`Application/octet-stream` means that the sender of the data (probably an HTTP server) had no idea what the data is. It's just an arbitrary data dump. The example output you give confirms that it's not UTF-8 since there shouldn't be any 0 bytes. It might be `UTF-16-be` but then, it must be an even number of input bytes and you have 5.

That means the input data isn't valid in some way. Maybe if you speak with the person who gave it to you or which wrote the producer, that would help to find out what the data is supposed to be. Chances are it's not text at all.

Comment: hi aaron, I can open it with my editor Geany. Thank you very much for the explaination.